# How do I cut a lap in the middle of a 2x6 that does not extend to either end of the board without using a router?

Tags: technique

I need to cut a 2" x 1/2" lap in the middle of a 2x6 (5-1/2" on either end will NOT be cut...only the middle 3 feet).  Without a router or router table, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Something like this:[image]

Comment: If you have a drill press, you could use a forstner bit to remove the bulk of the material and the come back with a chisel to get the edges and corners.

Comment: I think you should list what tools you do have available, since this could be done purely using hand tools, certain power tools or a mixture of the two. No point in recommending the method using a table saw if you don't own one!

Comment: I'm not understanding the dimensions of the board, nor the size of the lap that is being cut. Can you clarify? Even a rudimentary drawing would help.

Comment: @CharlieKilian I had difficulty too! It's a notch 3 feet long in the edge of 2" thick material, 1/2" deep.

Comment: Still need a sketch; not visualizing anything I'd call a lap...

Comment: @AstPace We sure about that Sketchup image? That's exactly what I was visualising first! Then I re-read it and thought something completely different.

Comment: You could clamp the board down flat on your bench, then cut a series of parallel shallow cuts with your circular saw almost up to the ends of the "lap." Chiseling out the waste at that point is fairly trivial. Square up the ends with a chisel, as well. (I'm new at this, but also have limited tools and have had to get creative.)

Comment: @Graphus Lacking any feedback from OP, I figure that this diagram gives us all the same problem to solve.  And IMHO it is exactly what was described.:)

Answer (score 6):

1. Cut the edges of your lap with a handsaw (fine-tune the edges later with a chisel, if you like).
2. Cut a few more lines into the wood down the length of the lap to prevent splits from running out of control in the next step.
3. Use a chisel and mallet to quickly knock out the wood in between the edges.
4. Carefully pare down to the line using a sharp chisel and the force of your hand/body.

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove 1/2" of material from the face of the board, for 3 feet in the middle of the board? Sounds like that would be a good job for a bandsaw. Turn the board on edge and cut the two edges. Make a couple of relief cuts along your desired cut, and then cut out the bulk of the material. Flip the board around to get the other edge. Clean up with a chisel or plane.

If you don't have a bandsaw, a jigsaw may work, although you'll need to be careful to keep the base perpendicular to your board. A jig (yes, a jig for your jigsaw :)) may be useful here, which may just be a second 2x6 on edge.

Comment: I think OP is not cutting the full 5 1/2" from the face - only 2" x 1/2".  Thus a band saw simply is not a way to do it.